# How to handle a simple login and sign up form in java swing with jdbc

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I created a simple java programm using Java swing for a form which will give options to sign in as well as sign up. When entering data into the textareas and pressing the relevant buttons, the console didn't show any error message or exception message. But when checking the database there is no change updated when using the sign up form. Also for both button i added some output lines which will print successfully signed in and signed up. That message is also not coming. I created the GUI interface using the GUI form creator in Intellij. Below is my code

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class WelcomeScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label4;
    private JLabel label6;
    private JLabel label5;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JLabel label7;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JPasswordField passwordField1;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JPasswordField passwordField2;
    private JPasswordField passwordField3;
    private JButton signInButton;
    private JButton signUpButton;

    public WelcomeScreen(){
        add(panel);
        setTitle("University Management System");
        setSize(600,600);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // entry fields in sign in form JTextField and JPassword
        String u1 = textField1.getText();
        char[] pw1 = passwordField1.getPassword();
        String p1 = new String(pw1);
        //entry fields in sign up form JTextField and JPassword
        String u2 = textField2.getText();
        char[] pw2 = passwordField2.getPassword();
        char[] pw3 = passwordField3.getPassword();
        String p2 = new String(pw2);
        String p3 = new String(pw3);
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase", "root", "Luxan@22"
            );
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            if(e.getSource() == signUpButton) {
                try{
                    if(p2.equals(p3) == true) {

                        PreparedStatement sts = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
                        sts.setString(1, u2);
                        sts.setString(2, p2);
                        sts.executeUpdate();
                        System.out.println("You are successfully signed up");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Passwords are not matching");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e3){
                    System.out.println("An error occurred while signing up");
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else if(e.getSource() == signInButton) {
                try{
                    PreparedStatement sts = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
                    sts.setString(1, u1);
                    sts.setString(2, p1);
                    ResultSet result = sts.executeQuery();
                    if( result.next())
                        System.out.println("You are successfully logged in");
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect username and password");
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e1){
                    System.out.println("An error occurred while signing in");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            con.close();

        }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("An exception occured");
                e2.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: This `if(p2.equals(p3) == true) {` is not how you compare char arrays. Please see the duplicate question

Comment: If you print out something in the beginning of `actionPerformed()` does it get printed when you press a button? The code you're showing is missing a lot of things and wouldn't run at all like that.